# How to prove this problem about component of $R^{ω}$?

Tags: general-topology

> **Problem:** Consider $\Bbb R^\omega$ with the uniform topology. Show that $\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2,\dots)$ and $\mathbf y = (y_1,y_2,\dots)$ lie in the same component of $\Bbb R^\omega $ if and only if the sequence
> $\mathbf x -\mathbf y = (x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2,\dots)$ is bounded.

I can prove it from left: assume that $|x_i-y_i| ≤ M$ for all $i∈\omega$.
Consider $f(t)=t\mathbf x +(1-t)\mathbf y$. We can check that $f$ is a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R^\omega$. Then $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ can be joined by $f(t)$, so $\mathbf x $ and $\mathbf y$ lie in the same component.
But, how to prove it from right?

Comment: What does sox and xand mean?   Raw Tex is unacceptable.

Comment: Try showing the contrapositive: If $\|\mathbf x - \mathbf y\|_\infty = \infty$, then there is a disconnection separating $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$.